# Open whatsapp statuses automatically with Python - Hide the annoying whatsapp status circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, whatsapp, whatsapi

Hi when a status is posted on whatsapp then a new circle is posted next to status and it stays there until all the statuses are viewed - this circle drives me and a lot of other people mad.

Is there way to get rid of it or i was thinking maybe with python or some other programing language, we could do something which as soon as someone posts a whatsapp status, then it views it automatically and then that circle will never be there !

Any ideas or solutions about this ?

Comment: can you add image about it?

Answer (score 0):

Apply web scraping to remove the unwanted circles.

Comment: Please give more details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: More information ?